# How can you create multiple DataGridViews at runtime using a variable for the name

Tags: vb.net, variables, datagridview

I have been looking for 2 days for an answer but so far can not find one that works. This is what I am trying to do:

I have read a list of excel worksheets into an array using VB.NET
Now I want to create a DataGridview for each sheet but I can not figure out how use the sheet name, as a variable, from the array to create the DataGridView's.

I have tried the following:

```
Dim dgvName as String = array(0)
Dim dgvName As New DatGridView
```

and

```
For x = 0 to array.length -1
   Dim array(x) As New DataGridView
Next
```

Neither of these work.

Can anyone explain how I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cant.  Variables have to be defined at compile time.  Create a list to store the dgv objects

Comment: thank you. I will look up how to do a list of dgv objects.

Comment: `Private myDGVs As New List(of DataGridView)` then just `.Add` the DGVs you create to it

Comment: You don't have to look up how to do a list of `DataGridViews`.  A `List` is a `List`.  Don't try to complicate things.  If you can work with `Integers` or `Strings` in a `List` then you already know how to use a `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't create multiple DataGridViews because it is too heavy. Most likely you would look at one sheet at the time and you can do it in single grid view by simply changing its `DataSource`.

Here is what you generally need to do

1. Use Microsoft.Ace.OleDb provider to connect to Excel (connection)
2. Use `OleDbDataAdapter` to fill `DataSet`. The beauty of the provider in #1 is that you can work with Excel like any DB table, i.e. `Select * from sheet_name`
3. Once you fill `DataSet`, where each `DataTable` will represent a sheet in your workbook, you assign `gridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)`
4. Create logic, where user clicks something and changes index in `dataSet.Tables(index)`. This way you can have one grid.

You can easily research each of the items on the list. There are plenty of resources on this.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Went out sick for several days. This is the solution that works best for my situation. Thank you very much

Comment: @mbcharney I hope you didn't have much difficulty to google for these things. It is easy as long as design is ok

Comment: No it was fine. I have it working now using your suggestion. Again thanks.